# Autocomplete Styling customization

Tags: autocomplete, customization, styling

For some unavoidable reason, I had to wrap autocomplete result in two divs, so my final output is as

```
<div id="resultDiv">
    <div id="scrollerDiv">
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
```

But this removes all styling and events from my result (i.e. `<li>`s). My 'select' event was getting called, results were navigatable using up and down arrows, background of selected record was getting highlighted etc. before adding these divs but all this functionality is gone. Is there any change/s I can do in *'jquery.ui.autocomplete.js'* and/or '*query.ui.css*' to add this div existance and get everything working back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by applying css class of `<ul>` to `<div>` dynamically.